Turns rows into columns
I am using SQL Server 2012 and I am trying to "pivot" rows to columns per key.
Maximum rows per set is 4.
I have prepared a sample code in order to describe it better
DECLARE @resu TABLE
              (
                  header_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  appointment_id numeric(10, 0) null,
                  client_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  on_date        datetime       null,
                  on_time        char(5)        null,
                  room_id        numeric(10, 0) null
              )

INSERT @resu
SELECT 654661,2784760,232834,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9
INSERT @resu
SELECT 654661,2784761,232845,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9
INSERT @resu
SELECT 654661,2784762,232836,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9
INSERT @resu
SELECT 654661,2784763,232837,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','13:00',9
INSERT @resu
SELECT 654662,2784798,232888,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9
INSERT @resu
SELECT 654662,2784799,232889,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9

select * from @resu

The result I am trying to produce is
 --header_id then the client_ids order by appointment_id and then the on_date, on_time, room_id which are common for all these records
    --the max rows per header_id is 4
header_id,client_id1,client_id2,client_id3,client_id4,on_date,on_time,room_id
    654661,232834,232845,232836,232837,'2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9
    654662,232888,232889,null,null,'2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9


So what is your question? What is the logic to get from your sample data to your expected results? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What about the 100s (probably 1,000s) of posts on pivoting that already exist on the site didn't you understand?

I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server?rq=2 but my case is completely different.

If you keep on_date and on_time separately - why don't you use DATE for on_date , and TIME for on_time ? Why use a string type for your on_time ??? Those proper datatypes have been available since SQL Server 2008.....

So, again, what is your question, logic, attempt, failure reason, and lack of understanding?

An elegant way to do it rather than creating 4 IF blocks.

and a cursor...

As an FYI, as well, SQL Server 2012 reach end of life around 2 years ago; you really need to implement your upgrade path to get onto a fully supported version of SQL Server.

@marc_s Unfortunately the database pre-existed. This is a sample code.

assuming your data is correct
CREATE  TABLE resu 
              (
                  header_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  appointment_id numeric(10, 0) null,
                  client_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  on_date        datetime       null,
                  on_time        char(5)        null,
                  room_id        numeric(10, 0) null
              )

INSERT INTO resu
(header_id,appointment_id, client_id ,on_date ,on_time,room_id )
VALUES
(654661,2784760,232834,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784761,232845,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784762,232836,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784763,232837,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),---error---
(654662,2784798,232888,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9),
(654662,2784799,232889,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9);


use pivot,concat, maxand row_number together
SELECT header_id,
MAX([client_id1]) client_id1, 
MAX([client_id2]) client_id2, 
MAX([client_id3] )client_id3 , 
MAX([client_id4] )client_id4 ,
MIN(on_date ) on_date,
MIN(on_time) on_time,
MIN(room_id)  room_id   
FROM (
select header_id,
       [client_id1], 
       [client_id2], 
       [client_id3], 
       [client_id4],
       on_date ,
        on_time,
        room_id    
from 
(
select  header_id,
        client_id ,
  CONCAT('client_id',ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY header_id ORDER BY appointment_id,on_date, on_time, room_id)) PT,
         on_date ,
         on_time,
         room_id      
  from resu

) src
pivot
(
  MAX(client_id)
  for PT in ([client_id1], [client_id2], [client_id3], [client_id4])
) piv
)
  A
  GROUP BY header_id


dbfiddle
however I think your input data in site has errors
and by correcting data
CREATE  TABLE resu 
              (
                  header_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  appointment_id numeric(10, 0) null,
                  client_id      numeric(10, 0) null,
                  on_date        datetime       null,
                  on_time        char(5)        null,
                  room_id        numeric(10, 0) null
              )

INSERT INTO resu
(header_id,appointment_id, client_id ,on_date ,on_time,room_id )
VALUES
(654661,2784760,232834,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784761,232845,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784762,232836,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),
(654661,2784763,232837,   '2023-04-17 00:00:00.000','13:00',9),--corrected
(654662,2784798,232888,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9),
(654662,2784799,232889,   '2023-04-18 00:00:00.000','15:00',9);

use pivot,row_numberand concatonly
select header_id,
       [client_id1], 
       [client_id2], 
       [client_id3], 
       [client_id4],
       on_date ,
        on_time,
        room_id    
from 
(
select  header_id,
        client_id ,
  CONCAT('client_id',ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY header_id ORDER BY appointment_id,on_date, on_time, room_id)) PT,
         on_date ,
         on_time,
         room_id      
  from resu

) src
pivot
(
  MAX(client_id)
  for PT in ([client_id1], [client_id2], [client_id3], [client_id4])
) piv;


dbfiddle
